# Click checkbox only when blank

Tags: applescript, safari, javascript

I use:

```
tell document 1 of application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click();"
end tell
```

to click on a checkbox, but would it be possible to do it only when the checkbox is blank?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I don't know much JavaScript , but isn't there a way to find out whether the checkbox is selected **using JavaScript**, and then conditionally select it? You could then expand the JavaScript code with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.classname:not(:checked)').click();
```

> An unchecked checkbox can be selected by using the negation pseudo-class:
>
> ```
> :not(:checked)
> ```

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#checked

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is to activate that box only if it is blank.

Comment: @Pepe What does ‘blank’ mean if not checked then?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not explained clearly: if the check box is disabled (blank) I want to click, but if it is enabled I DO NOT want to click.

Comment: @Pepe That is what this answer does! It find the check box with that class name that is `:not(:checked)` and clicks it. If the check box is checked, nothing will match that query so nothing will be returned to click on.

Comment: It always clicks, whether it is blank or not. Above I have attached the script.